# Выпадающие списки в Bootstrap 2 не работают

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

В Bootstrap версии 2.3 не работают выпадающие списки

```
<<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

Шаблон Bootstrap 101

```
    <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="../js/bootstrap 2.2.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>

                <ul class="nav">
                    <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                </ul>
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    Меню<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>

                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">
                    Меню<b class="caret"></b></a>

                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                        <li class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Текст подпункта</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Вот эта конечная работающая версия ....!!! Всем спасибо !!!

Comment: <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script> что то одно нужно отключить

Comment: @kandellak не просто отключить, а еще и быть уверенным, что бутстрап собран с dropdown

Comment: !function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
  * ========================= */

  var toggle = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
    , Dropdown = function (element) {
        var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
        $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
          $el.parent().removeClass('open')
        })
      }
и тому подобное .... ив min.js и в .js есть эта функция , пробовал что то отключать не помогает...

Comment: зачем вы один и тот же скрипт, подключили 4 раза на странице?) http://codepen.io/bustexz/pen/LZZQXW все работает...

Comment: отключил не помогло ... писал же, оставил только <script src="../js/bootstrap.js"></script>; <script src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> ; <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> в хэаде...

Comment: @Aleksandr_sf ты зайди и посмотри, я подключил на страницу с примером jquery, bootstrap.js и bootstrap.css и все работает. Опять же у тебя 2 раза подключен jquery плагин, 2 раза подключены стили (хоть именно они не играют роли). Отключишь jquery сверху, все должно будет заработать

Comment: @Aleksandr_sf вот на https://jsfiddle.net/9qjmLfn1/ тоже все работает

Comment: я все делал как вы сказали,  не работает ... скажите js подключали второй версии

Comment: @Aleksandr_sf он вам в консоль что нибудь пишет? В данный момент у вас нет jquery плагина вовсе в коде

Comment: Василий Барбашев большое спасибо вам как только добавил к себе строчку <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script> все заработало ....Еще раз спасибо !!

Comment: <script src="../js/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script> - С вот этим не работает ...

Comment: @Aleksandr_sf Перенесите все уточнения из комментариев в тело вопроса, для этого используйте кнопку [edit], расположенную под телом вопроса.